# Generate numbers from normal distribution

Tags: r

I know that if I want to generate for example 120 numbers from normal distribution with mean 30 and standard deviation 20 i can do it by command :

```
x=rnorm(120,30,20)
```

But what if I want to generate 100 times 120 numbers from above normal distribution ?

Do we have in R any function to do this directly ?

Comment: See `help("replicate")`

Comment: most efficient to do something like `matrix(rnorm(100*120,30,20),nrow=100)`

Comment: `rnorm(120*100, 30,20)` will do that - but I suspect your question should say you want 100 *sets* of random numbers in order to something with each set. So Ben Bolker's answer will put each set into each row of a matrix. What do you want to do with your random numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed by @duckmayr

```
replicate(100, rnorm(120, 30, 20), simplify = TRUE) # if you want to generate a matrix

replicate(100, rnorm(120, 30, 20), simplify = FALSE) # if you want to generate a list
```